# Any guidelines available for planning and designing IAM (user authentication and permissions) for a CORDA network/Node?

Tags: corda

Any guidelines available for planning and designing IAM (user authentication and permissions) for a CORDA network/Node?
Is there a concept of User Role in Corda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Corda network, it is provided by the Corda Enterprise Network Manager (CENM): https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.5/user-admin.html .

For a single Corda node, you can configure the RPC access in the `node.conf` and use them to authorize users to access node functionalities: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/tutorial-clientrpc-api.html#defining-rpc-credentials-and-permissions .

Comment: Is it possible to provide multiple users access to one node? The scenario where there is an ORGANIZATION (node) with various employees. Each employee will have a separate user credentials and user permissions.

Comment: Yes you can do that with RPC access.

Comment: since each user does not have a KEY associated, will it be still using the KEY of the node for actions?

Comment: @user3760894 The RPC credentials should be made for a RPC client. If you need to create users that connect to that RPC client, it would be better to handle that at client level, not at Corda level.

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa so we need to implement it with spring security?

Comment: Any technology would make the job. It is completely outside the scope of Corda.