# Does Corda support user credentials for Accounts / Party?

Tags: corda

Does Corda support user credentials for Accounts / Party? Here there is a common username, password for the node access through RPC. Is there a way to validate the user (Node user / Account) in Corda as well?

Application user (Node user / Account) <----> Application <----> RPC Client <----> Cordapp (Node)

Comment: I already answered you in this other question, right (in the comments)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67867353/any-guidelines-available-for-planning-and-designing-iam-user-authentication-and

Comment: There I couldn't get answer for this question - "since each user does not have a KEY associated, will it be still using the KEY of the node for actions?"

Also as RPC login is using common credentials, would need a user specific access. 

Based on this documentation, it is possible to define a set of users in a external database. Isn't this a better way than configuring rpcusers in config file?
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.7/node/operating/clientrpc.html

Need to check whether this applies to Node users and account SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the only way to connect an external client to a node is using the Corda RPC Client
- the configuration of the user that can connect to the RPC Client (i.e. username, password, permissions) is in the `node.conf` (explained [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.7/node/operating/clientrpc.html#building-the-corda-rpc-client))
- you can create multiple users in the `node.conf`. Up to you to assign these users to a node administrator, or to external users, depending on your security policies. You can set different permissions for each of them, and also set which CorDapp flows they can access to.
- If your CorDapp does use Accounts (i.e the account library), and you want them to "run flows" (though, consider that accounts in Corda do not run flows, but it's always the node that run flows on their behalf) from an external client (e.g. a Web app), you have the possibility to:

  1. create a RPC user in the `node.conf` for each account
  2. create only one user for the RPC client and manage the authentication and authorization of the external users at application level, not Corda level (e.g. JWT, external database, AWS Cognito, etc..). Once authorized, the user can access the RPC client from the Web app and
  3. a mix of the 1. and 2.

I would not recommend to delegate the authentication and authorization of external users only at Corda level. I would keep the concept of "accounts" in Corda and "external users" separated.

Comment: Thanks. So need to handle auth in the application side and also need to maintain a application user - corda accounts/node mapping the in the application. That will help to map the users. Also probably help in passing the Party name (as per the names in Corda) correctly to the RPC calls.

Comment: Yes. Never forget that "accounts" in Corda 4.x are only logical entities. So, effectively they do not do anything, it's always the node who runs flows etc.